# space between the two words is trimmed in rich:suggestionbox in jsf

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have a combobox (`suggestionbox` from RichFaces) that is connected via the `suggestionValues` attribute to a list of strings and some of these strings have spaces in the middle of the text and sometimes at the end, for example:

```
" This starts with a space"
"This ends with a space "
"This has two  spaces after the word two"
```

In these cases, the start and end spaces are removed and the two spaces in the middle of the last String are reduced to one space when they are selected from the suggestion list. I need to have the spaces preserved but this is currently impossible.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: we are not interested in your email, thanks

Comment: This does not seem to be an HTML/CSS issue. The spaces come from server side with the spaces already trimmed. It's RichFaces specific: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-9922 https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RF-3066

Answer (score 0):

- try using `&#160;` (an `&nbsp;`) instead of space?
- put `style="white-space: pre;"`

Answer (score 0):

I've recently discovered a similar issue and after some research it seems to be a bug in the Tidy parser, a workaround is to use the Neko parser instead which solved my issue:

http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#FilterConfiguration

As well as adding the previously mentioned CSS.